# Can't Get Apache to Dispaly "This works" page after new install!

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I have read countless answers and tried countless methods:

- [how reinstall apache2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111770/how-reinstall-apache2)
- [How can I host a domain/website on my new VPS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124261/how-can-i-host-a-domain-website-on-my-new-vps)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086011/why-is-php-not-running

Currently running:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I installed it using [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04) from digital ocean.

I've followed other guites to purge and reinstall but it has not worked. I can't see this DARN it WORKS page after I install it.

This is in my apache2.conf file:

```
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

This is in my 000-defualt.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       .

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html



        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Note:

- I did NOT INSTALL any additional packages as per Digital Oceans guide.
- I can't fine anything when I got here `http://myserver ip`

But if I run `curl http://icanhazip.com` it will show the raw code.
Almost giving up on this!

Comment: have you installed this on a **DO** VPS droplet? or did it locally? are you able to `telnet server_ip 80`?

Comment: Is your server actually running? What is the output of `sudo service apache2 status`?

Comment: ---AzkerM DO VPS droplet? i have to look that up. I tried TELNETTing.. and got  telnet myip 80
Trying myip...
Connected to 1myip.
Escape character is '^]'. @OrganicMarble Marble, i've had it running, restarted, paused off and everything..  regardless of the issue all guides instruct to restart the server, pause it, run it, and so on.. that's totally not the issue in question.

Comment: **DigitalOcean** in short for DO.. My bad I should've explained...

Comment: ohh no its not on their VPS.. its another one. but i have tried many other guides and they all have the same instructions.  i am running a bare-bone vps nothing installed at all.. just Ubunto

Comment: so, what is the output of that command?